# Backing up using Clonezilla, what's the order? Any better alternative?

Tags: backup

I want to run Clonezilla Live from a CD in order to backup my Ubuntu partition. With `dd` I know the command and would be confident I'm not going to trash the wrong HD. `dd` just takes too long unfortunately.

```
dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/dev/sdb1
```

I have tried Clonezilla Live but became confused with their terminology for source and target. Hence I didn't do anything, hoping to get some advice here first.

My question: Is the Clonezilla wizard asking for target first and source second, so that the first device I put will be the one whose data will be destroyed?

Alternatively is there some other way of backing up? For the PC partition (this is a dual boot machine) I use 'DriveImage XML', which is really fast (and you use the Knoppix LIVE CD for restoring). Something like that for Linux would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Clonezilla disk-to-disk option, you will first be prompted for a source drive, then the target drive. The target drive will be overwritten and all information on it will be lost.

This is in contrast to the other option, disk-to-image, where you are first asked to select a target device which the image will be saved at. Then, at the end, you will be asked what drive(or drives) you want to include.

Hope this comes to help.

Comment: I was using disk-to-image, hence the confusion. I'm wanting back up rather than create a clone of the partition.

Comment: Yes, totally understable.

It should be pretty straight forward from there on.

Comment: That worked in that it didn't trash my computer. It actually backed up all the sda partitions. (I must have missed the include part). So the whole of my computer (Windows and Linux partitions) is backed up.

Comment: That's great to hear, Chris! :-)